# How to give the calculated width in Bootstrap 3 Progress Bars?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have one Page which has the final set of files in table order and I have the count of those files. In those files  I have open and closed files as a status.

I want show that closed files percentage in progress bar.Here based on width only the progress bar is changing.

Now my question is How to give the calculated value as a width. I am using bootstrap 3.

can someone guide me in the right direction.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 55%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">55%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is your actual problem, how to get the percentage or how to set the percentage in progress bar?

Comment: @OM PRAKASH Like I have 80 files in that 50 files are closed and 30 are open , according to the closed files count the progress bar should change. the total files count might vary all the time.

Comment: So, calculate the percentage and set the width and value. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// total files
let totalFiles = 42;

// closed files
let closedFiles = 30;

// find progress bar
const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress-bar[role="progressbar"]');

// find remaining progress bar
const remainingBar = document.querySelector('.progress-bar[role="remaining"]');

function onFileChange() {
  // calculate percentage
  let percentage = Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(closedFiles / totalFiles * 100), 0), 100);
  // calculate remaining percentage
  let remaining = 100-percentage;

  // apply percentage
  progressBar.style.width = percentage + '%';
  progressBar.innerText = percentage + '%';
  remainingBar.style.width = remaining + '%';
  remainingBar.innerText = remaining + '%';
}







// simulate file change
document.querySelector('#totalFiles').addEventListener('change', e => {
  totalFiles = e.target.value;
  onFileChange();
});
document.querySelector('#closedFiles').addEventListener('change', e => {
  closedFiles = e.target.value;
  onFileChange();
});

onFileChange();
```

```css
.progress-bar[role="remaining"] {
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">55%</div>
      <div class="progress-bar" role="remaining" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">45%</div>
    </div>
  </div>





  <!-- Simulatet file change controls -->
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="totalFiles">Total Files</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="totalFiles" placeholder="Total Files" value="42">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="closedFiles">Closed Files</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="closedFiles" placeholder="Closed Files" value="30" />
    </div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry,I am new to this. May I know how this progress-bar setting the width value. Like How it is finding ?

Comment: @Wolverine Basically you calculate the percentage by current status. e.g. 4 files out of 10 so: `4 / 10 * 100%` and you get 40%. Then shove it into its style `width: 40%`.

Comment: // find progress bar
const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress-bar'); -> this line exactly I didn't get. Like How it is finding, Is it by class name?

Comment: @Wolverine This is the part that js finds the progress bar element, so it can change its styles and texts etc, pretty basic stuff, if you have used `jQuery`, it's equivalent to `const progressBar = $('.progress-bar')`

Comment: In the same scenario, If 30 files are closed means other 12 files are open, can we indicate that open file percentage also in the same progress bar? Like 71% are closed and 29% are open. Is this Possible in the same progress bar ?

Comment: @Wolverine Of course, I updated it, just by adding one additional bar in `progress` div.

Comment: have to do role as remaining :) Thank You

Comment: @Wolverine Doesn't have to be, bootstrap has no idea what `remaining` is and has no associated style for it. It's just for naming convention and give it a unique identity so you can style it :)